# Vue.Js, my function is called many times for no reason

Tags: vue.js

In my App, my getphohto(budget) must return **3** photos in **console.log**. But it's called many times.

This makes my serveur bug and not executing my javascript. So i would like to fix it but i don't know where is my problem ?

In blade :

```
<a class="col-md-2" v-for="budget in budgets">
  <img :src="getphoto(budget)">
</a>
```

In Js

```
getBudgets() {
    axios.get('/getbudgets')
        .then(response => {

            this.budgets = response.data;

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('errors: ', error);
        })
},

getphoto(budget) {
    console.log('#', budget.person.photo);
    return "img/" + budget.person.photo;
},
```

Notice : All functions [1-7] are axios get and simples.

Thank you for help !

[image]

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. `getphoto` is called multiple times, because data used in your render function changes, and `getphoto` is a method (as opposed to a computed property) that is always called.

Comment: thx for ur interest. any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say. As @Sumurai8 said, because data changes, vue re-renders the template and calls `getphoto` again. What is the ** All functions [1-7] are axios get and simples**?

Comment: Thank you for ur interest , i solve that with removing getphoto and use items.map

Answer (score 0):

i solve that with items.maps

```
getBudgets () {
               axios.get('/getbudgets')
               .then(response => {
                  this.budgets = response.data;
                   let items = response.data;
                   this.budgets = items.map((item)=>{
                   item.person.photo = '/img/' + item.person.photo
                    console.log('#', item.person.photo);
                     console.log('#1', );
                     return item;

                    });

               })
               .catch(error => {
                   console.log('errors: ', error);
               })
               },
```

Then i removed **getphoto()** from my code and in  i wrote that

```
<img :src=budget.person.photo>
```